# Generate PDF from tableView include offscreen part

Tags: ios, swift

```
extension UITableView {

   public func generateToPDF() -> Data? {
        let priorBounds = self.bounds
        let fittedSize = self.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width:priorBounds.size.width, height: self.contentSize.height))
        self.bounds = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width:fittedSize.width, height:fittedSize.height)
        let pdfPageBounds = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height:self.frame.height)

        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        var pageOriginY: CGFloat = 0
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds, nil)
        while pageOriginY < fittedSize.height {
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil)
            UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.saveGState()
            UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.translateBy(x: 0, y: -pageOriginY)
            self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
            UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.restoreGState()
            pageOriginY += pdfPageBounds.size.height
        }
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
        self.bounds = priorBounds
        return pdfData.copy() as? Data
    }
}
```

Comment: not show for offscreen part - show this coding part.

Comment: Hi, have you tried to write the file and check if the actual file generated has all pages or not?

https://www.swiftdevcenter.com/create-pdf-from-uiview-wkwebview-and-uitableview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Finally I figure it out by myself, hope it helps someone who looking for it.*

1. **Render entire tableview content as UIImage and put it in UIImageView**

   ```
   func getPdf() -> Data? {
           UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.contentSize, false, 0)
           self.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)
           self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

           let interationCount: Int = Int(ceil(self.contentSize.height / self.bounds.size.height))
           for i in 0..<interationCount {
               self.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: Int(self.bounds.size.height) * i), animated: false)
               self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
           }

           let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
           let pdfImg: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
           UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

           return self.createPDFFromUIView(pdfImg: pdfImg)

   }
   ```

   2. **Convert UIImageView(which contains image of pdf) to pdf**

      ```
      private func createPDFFromUIView(pdfImg: UIView) -> Data? {
          let pdfData = NSMutableData()
          UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfImg.bounds, nil)
          UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
          pdfImg.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
          UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

          return pdfData.copy() as? Data
      }
      ```